# Objects pass through the player object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

[image]

I have spheres and a player gameObjects, the balls enter the player even though it has a rigid body and a collider, this is how the player is defined:

[image]

It has several child objects but none of them has a rigid body or a collider.

This is how the spheres are defined with its sphere child:

[image]
[image]

The spheres are moved only like this `transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (dir.normalized * ForceFactor);`

So what is causing them to go into the player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your player and enemy object both has collider's property `IsTrigger` enabled. Check out [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) on trigger - it's mentioned that trigger doesn't register a collision. You should use not trigger mode colliders (for both object) to register collision properly and don't allow object to pass through each other